# python regex relace for a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to apply regex on python for following code. I want replace usa_f1_t1 with usa.

for ex: my input would be usa_f1, usa_tt1_f1_v1, usa_us_t1_v1 , us_us_v1

for all these cases i would want to ignore string part where anything coming numeric

usa_tt1_f1_v1  - it should give **usa** as result

usa_us_t1_v1 - it should give **usa_us** as result

usa_f1 - it should give **usa** as result

usa_phone - it should give **usa_phone** as result

I am trying following code. please help as am new to python

```
import re

Country_name = "usa_us_f1_t1_v1"
new_result = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', '', Country_name)

# Display the Content
print(new_result)
```

Comment: Your regex will match the underscores too; why do you expect it not to?

Comment: Looks like you want `(?:_[A-Za-z]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]*)+`

Comment: Maybe without a regex, `'_'.join([x for x in s.split('_') if x.isalpha()])`? See https://ideone.com/c7DqPS

Comment: Ok, I see the comment is helpful, let's convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any regex:

```py
'_'.join([x for x in s.split('_') if x.isalpha()])
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/c7DqPS).

*What does it it do?*

- `s.split('_')` - splits the string with underscores
- then the list comprehension keeps only those chunks (`x`) that fully consist of letters (`.isalpha()` does that check).